# Is there a way to add a hook on spark executor shutdown

Tags: java, apache-spark

I need to close some resources on the executor process when the executor is shutting down. Is there a way in spark to add a shutdown or close hook ?

Comment: Have you tried adding a JVM shutdown hook?

Comment: How do I do that ?